# .reversed() does not compile in blueJ

Tags: java

I have a method for sorting a table for a class i made.
everything else is fine except for the ".reserved" at the end of the method which prevents it from compiling. What can i do for my method to compile?

```
    public void sortTable(String division) {
    List<Team> teamsForDivision = teams.get(division);
    if (teamsForDivision == null) {
        return;
    }

    Collections.sort(teamsForDivision, new Comparator<Team>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
            return o1.getPoints() - o2.getPoints();
        }
    }.reversed());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling it with Java version >= 1.8 ?

Comment: Don't use "blueJ".

Comment: What is the error here?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the error reported by BlueJ, it is impossible to answer correctly, however:

```
   Collections.sort(teamsForDivision, new Comparator<Team>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
            return o1.getPoints() - o2.getPoints();
        }
    }.reversed());
```

If the compiler says that there is a syntax error, that some token is expected (such as "*Unexpected token {, expected )*"), try adding parenthesis or create a variable:

Using parenthesis:

```
   Collections.sort(teamsForDivision, (new Comparator<Team>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
            return o1.getPoints() - o2.getPoints();
        }
    }).reversed());
```

Using a variable:

```
   Comparator<Team> pointComparator = new Comparator<Team>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
            return o1.getPoints() - o2.getPoints();
        }
   };
   Collections.sort(teamsForDivision, pointComparator.reversed());
```

If the compiler warns you that the method `reversed` does not exists, which is most likely here, then it means the compiler use a version below Java 8 (the method was added in Java 8) however reversing this is not hard:

```
Comparator<Team> pointComparator = new Comparator<Team>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
    return -(o1.getPoints() - o2.getPoints());
  }
};
```

If possible, you should use `Integer::compare` instead:

```
Comparator<Team> pointComparator = new Comparator<Team>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
    return -Integer.compare(o1.getPoints(), o2.getPoints());
  }
}
```

Finally, you could also use lambda (if Java 8 is supported):

```
Comparator<Team> c = Comparator.comparingInt(Team::getPoints).reversed();
```

Alternatively, you may want to upgrade your version of BlueJ: the [site](https://bluej.org/faq.html#bluej-with-java-9-plus) says that version 4.1.2++ supports Java 8:

> **Can I run BlueJ with Java 9, 10, 11...?**
>
> The current version of BlueJ (4.1.2) requires Java 8. Most users (on
>   either Windows or Mac platforms) should run BlueJ with the same JDK
>   that it is bundled with – other versions have not been tested.
>
> A future release of BlueJ will work with (and require) a later Java
>   version. At this point in time we expect that BlueJ 4.2.0 will work
>   with Java 11.